# API google map не работает в angular8-yandex-maps

Tags: angular, google-maps-api, яндекс-карты

[image: Я использую бибилиотеку angular8-yandex-maps компонент из этого примера multiroute-pedestrian с апи гугла и получаю ошибку 403]

я не совсем уверен как работает апи гугла  и можно ли его использовать с яндекс картами [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Не понятно в чем вопрос, что значит работать использовать с яндекс картами? У гугла отдельный модуль для этого: например https://angular-maps.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я впервые работал с API и задал глуппый вопрос.
API гугла и яндекса не совместимы!